# How to create Listing in ebay sandbox?

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I am working with EBAY [REST API]. For this i am using SANDBOX [which is test enviornment of Ebay]. I have created a developer account and two sandbox test user.For acting as a buyer and seller.I am trying to create listing using seller account. i created the product in the inventory but when i publish offer it gives me error and i could not publish the offer. it give me error like create policies etc.

I want to create a product using seller account and then buy tht product using buyer account.

Is there any other way to create listing ?

I am following this : https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/guides/features-guide/content/basics/Call-SandboxTesting.html

Comment: I gave up on the sandbox, and developed everything live. I STILL don't know how to do this, even after writing a program that creates listings and updates the prices and quantities on the fly.

Comment: I have raised the question on their forum. it seems its a problem on their end. I have created the inventory using inventory api then created a offer and when i try to publish the offer it give me error that your return policy is not found. and when i try to create the return policy there are errors. its findout that its a bug on their site. Here is the link of question that i have posted . 
https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/37057/how-to-define-return-policy-for-publishing-my-offe.html

Comment: @JonathonPhilipChambers how to link my seller account to developer account to test in the sandbox i just want to get the listings on my live store. 
or i have to create the sandbox user using seller account email ? 
https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/37072/how-to-link-my-developer-account-to-ebay-seller-ac.html 
please look at this question. and assist me. thanks

Comment: That's an easy question to answer. "You don't." You use your developer account to create an app. You use your seller account to sell things. Once you have made your app, if you have made it properly, you can now use your app to log in to your seller account and grant the app permission to use your account.

The whole thing is designed to make sure that the developer account can NEVER be linked with a seller account, because eBay doesn't want to encourage people to share their account with an app developer.

Comment: @Jonathon I have created the Application and linked to my seller account. i have fetched the orders using api.ebay.com/sell/fulfillment/v1/order . But i am unable to fetch live inventory items and i am using this API api.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/inventory_item I am also unable to fetch item by sku. How to fetch items and item by sku using new sell rest api ?

Comment: in addition to that i am using production Environment not sandbox  Environment.

Comment: New question? Post a new question. We don't get points for responding to comments.

Comment: @Jonathon Sure ! here is the link of new question link  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059297/how-to-fetch-items-by-sku-on-ebay-using-sell-api-rest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have not specified the exact error you are getting when making the `publishOffer` call, I will try to outline the whole process for reference. The prerequisite steps for publishing an offer from your sandbox account are:

1. Create Payment, Fulfillment, and Return policies for your sandbox account. For this, you may call their respective APIs or you can use their [API Explorer](https://developer.ebay.com/my/api_test_tool?index=0&api=account&call=fulfillment_policy__POST&variation=json) which has sample policy requests ready to be executed or, easiest of all, you can manage your business policies from the sandbox website [here](https://www.bizpolicy.sandbox.ebay.com/businesspolicy/manage)
2. Create your inventory item using `createOrReplaceInventoryItem` call
3. Create an inventory location for the created item through the `createInventoryLocation` API call. Your offer won't publish without this.
4. Create an offer for the inventory item. Specify the offer details, such as fulfillment, payment, return policy IDs, category ID, inventory location ID, etc
5. Publish the offer

There are quite a few requirements, specific to the type of item you are providing through a listing, that you have to fulfill before eBay will let you publish the offer. You can find more information about this in the error response you get when publishing the offer.

With that said, eBay's sandbox has behaved very unreliably in the past from my experience. So if you are doing everything right and still running into problems, as a last resort, you can try creating the listing by using eBay's Trading API's AddItem call. I have personally found these sets of eBay APIs to be more reliable (albeit more outdated).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have posted the question related to return policy [here](https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/37057/how-to-define-return-policy-for-publishing-my-offe.html?childToView=37162#comment-37162) is the link of the question . 
Its findout that there is an issue on their side. thats why i was unable to publish the offer.

Comment: I have created the Application and  linked to my seller account. i have fetched the orders using https://api.ebay.com/sell/fulfillment/v1/order . But i am unable to fetch 
live inventory items and i am using this API https://api.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/inventory_item 
I am also unable to fetch item by sku. How to fetch items and item by sku using new sell rest api ?

Comment: @WaheedKhan GET https://api.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/inventory_item/{sku} is the standard way to get inventory by SKU. If you want to see the listing (live inventory) that was published on eBay Sandbox for a specific SKU, use GET https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/offer?sku={sku}. This will fetch the offer details for the SKU (if an offer has been created).

Comment: @WaheedKhan BTW, I am having trouble in fetchingOrders. If you want, we can connect over email (refer to my profile for my email)

Comment: I have tried these API's but its giving me 500 [ Internal server error ]. I am using  [this](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/inventory_item/methods/createOrReplaceInventoryItem) API's to get item by sku. And using [this](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/inventory_item/methods/getInventoryItems) API call. Both are giving me Internal server Error. I am using production account not sandbox. I think we can't get inventory item if these items are not created using inventory API.

Comment: Also i think we can't get inventory items if these are not created using inventory api. [look](https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/25072/how-to-get-all-live-listings.html)

Comment: what are the issues you are facing while getting orders ?

Comment: @TabishMir Thansk for this wonderful article. Issue still exist in eBay sandbox even today in 2023 mid and errors infact have increased multifolds